# How to Extract real part & Imaginary part from a String entry in the Pascal TextEdit GUI?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I am trying to create a Complex Number Calculator  using Delphi Pascal. The first part is to extract a string entry, separate the real & imaginary part by inserting a delimiter on 'i'. For Example: A number entry can be: **7+2i** or any other combination. This was my approach:

```
TForm2.btnExtractClick(Sender: TObject);
var sCode, pic: string;
    sConst: integer;
     im,re: integer;
    iConst: string;
    j,k, delimiterPos: integer;
 begin
 memDisplay.Clear;
 sCode := Edit1.Text;
 sConst := Pos (sCode, 'i');
 im := StrToInt(Copy(sCode, sConst - 1));
 Delete(sCode, sConstant - 1, im);
 re := StrToInt(sCode);
```

But I am getting the following error:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The substring which you search for should be the first argument to `Pos`.

Replace

```
Pos(sCode, 'i')
```

with

```
Pos('i', sCode)
```

This function is documented here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Pos

There are many further issues with your code, but this answers the primary question posed here, namely why `Pos` is returning `0`. I won't attempt to debug the rest of your code, not least because this isn't your real code because it contains compile errors.

To resolve the subsequent issues in your code you must learn to use the debugger. Step through the code and inspect the value of each of the local variables after each line of code has executed. Compare the values you see under the debugger with the values that you expect to see based on your paper based static analysis.

Comment: I couldn't figure the routine out. I wanted to know if there are other approaches whereby I can separate numbers, strings and arithmetic operators and assign them to a variable